# Video call flutter and agora

Tags: flutter, video, call, agora.io

I have implemented agora sdk in my flutter app , but when i tap on endCall button , if the one who tapped is the caller they both will end the call , but when i tapp on endCall from the receiver the video screen doesn't go away until the caller tap too on the endCall button .

Answer (score 0):

When you start a call users create their own instance of Agora RtcEngine and when you join a channel using it every user needs to individually leave the channel from the frontend. However, if you want a host or a certain person to have the privilege such that when that user leaves the call gets ended for all the other users in the channel then you need to set up a kicking rule. This can be done by the RESTful APIs that Agora provides. You can have a look at it over here: https://docs.agora.io/en/rtc/restfulapi/#/Banning%20user%20privileges/createKickingRule

Answer (score 0):

```
full code for agora flutter :
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/agora_rtc_engine.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:medical_app/view_model/Home/home_screen.dart';
// import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_engine.dart';

import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

import '../../main.dart';
import '../../utils/appID.dart';
import '../Profile/oppointment.dart';

class CallPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String token;

  const CallPage({ required this.token}) : super();

  @override
  _CallPageState createState() => _CallPageState();
}

class _CallPageState extends State<CallPage> {


  int? _remoteUid; // uid of the remote user
  bool _isJoined = false; // Indicates if the local user has joined the channel
   RtcEngine? agoraEngine;
   // Agora engine instance
  int uid = 0;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> scaffoldMessengerKey =
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>(); // Global key to access the scaffold

  showMessage(String message) {
    scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
    ));
  }

  Future<void> _handleCameraAndMic(Permission permission) async {
    final status = await permission.request();
    print(status);
  }
   bool engineload = true;
  @override
  void initState() {

    setupVideoSDKEngine();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    _handleCameraAndMic(Permission.camera);
    _handleCameraAndMic(Permission.microphone);
    await setupVideoSDKEngine();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  // Build UI
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     debugPrint("The Agora Token is ......******************* ${widget.token}");
    return Scaffold(
        key:scaffoldMessengerKey,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Get started with Video Calling'),
            leading: IconButton(onPressed: () async {

                  leave();
                 await agoraEngine!.leaveChannel();
                await agoraEngine!.release();
                Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return const HomeScreen();
                }), (route) => false);


            }, icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),),
          ),
          body: engineload ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),): ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 4),
            children: [
              // Container for the local video
              Container(
                height: 240,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
                child: Center(child: _localPreview()),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              //Container for the Remote video
              Container(
                height: 240,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
                child: Center(child: _remoteVideo()),
              ),
              // Button Row
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: _isJoined ? null : () => {join()},
                      child: const Text("Join"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: _isJoined ? () => {leave()} : null,
                      child: const Text("Leave"),
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
              // Button Row ends
            ],
          ));

  }

// Display local video preview
  Widget _localPreview() {
    if (_isJoined) {
      return AgoraVideoView(
        controller: VideoViewController(
          rtcEngine: agoraEngine!,
          canvas:  VideoCanvas(uid: uid),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return const Text(
        'Join a channel',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }
  }

// Display remote user's video
  Widget _remoteVideo() {
    if (_remoteUid != null) {
      return AgoraVideoView(
        controller: VideoViewController.remote(
          rtcEngine: agoraEngine!,
          canvas: VideoCanvas(uid: _remoteUid),
          connection: const RtcConnection(channelId:"Input Channel Here"),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      String msg = '';
      if (_isJoined) msg = 'Waiting for a remote user to join';
      return Text(
        msg,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> setupVideoSDKEngine() async {
    // retrieve or request camera and microphone permissions
    await [Permission.microphone, Permission.camera].request();

    //create an instance of the Agora engine
     agoraEngine = createAgoraRtcEngine();
    await agoraEngine!.initialize(RtcEngineContext(appId: appID)).then((value) {
        setState(() {
          engineload = false;
        });
      debugPrint("Engine connected");
    });

    await agoraEngine!.enableVideo();

    // Register the event handler
    agoraEngine!.registerEventHandler(
      RtcEngineEventHandler(
        onJoinChannelSuccess: (RtcConnection connection, int elapsed) {
          showMessage(
              "Local user uid:${connection.localUid} joined the channel");
          setState(() {
            _isJoined = true;
          });
        },
        onUserJoined: (RtcConnection connection, int remoteUid, int elapsed) {
          showMessage("Remote user uid:$remoteUid joined the channel");
          setState(() {
            _remoteUid = remoteUid;
          });
        },
        onUserOffline: (RtcConnection connection, int remoteUid,
            UserOfflineReasonType reason) {
          showMessage("Remote user uid:$remoteUid left the channel");
          setState(() {
            _remoteUid = 1;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void join() async {
    await agoraEngine!.startPreview();
    debugPrint("Join is cliked");
    // Set channel options including the client role and channel profile
    ChannelMediaOptions options = const ChannelMediaOptions(
      clientRoleType: ClientRoleType.clientRoleBroadcaster,
      channelProfile: ChannelProfileType.channelProfileCommunication,
    );

    await agoraEngine!.joinChannel(
      token: widget.token,
      channelId: "Enter your Channel name here",
      options: options,
      uid:uid,
    ).then((value) {
      debugPrint("Agora Connected");
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      debugPrint("The Agora Error is ... $error");
    }).then((value) {
      debugPrint("The Call is joined");
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
        debugPrint("The Agora Join Error : $error");
    });
  }

  void leave() async {
    setState(() {
      _isJoined = false;
      _remoteUid = 1;
    });
   await agoraEngine!.leaveChannel();
    await agoraEngine!.release();
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return const HomeScreen();
    }), (route) => false);
  }

// Release the resources when you leave
  @override
  void dispose() async {
    await agoraEngine!.leaveChannel();
    await agoraEngine!.release();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```